# How to draw lines,circles in a tableview

Tags: iphone

I need some drawings in my tableview. How can i do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it.  WHat have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom UITableViewCell. Google for "custom UITableViewCell" and choose a tutorial for your taste (Interface Builder centric or a code centric)

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITableViewCell and use [CGContext](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) to draw on the contentView (or the backgroundView/selectedBackgroundView if necessary). You can also draw on the header/footer of the table or on the header/footer of each section (check the UITableView docs on how to access them)